# how to shorten the logic to assign new or default value in php

Tags: php

I have following code in php:

```
$mode = $this->input->get('mode'); // may return string or boolean false
if(!$mode)
    $mode = 'default';
```

how can shorten this code to one line with fastest execution

Is this perfect one:

```
$mode = ($mode=$this->input->get('mode'))?$mode:'default';
```

Comment: Are you sure that's slow? I'd vote to keep your code simple until it's proven that the loss of readability is worth some measurable performance change.

Comment: What if $this->input->get('mode') returns an empty string? Should it be treated as false (as your code is doing now) or as an assigned string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mode = $this->input->get('mode') or $mode = "default";
```

But why bother for something this small?

Please note that the actual result of evaluating the above expression is `true` but that expression is not assigned to anything. If we were to do `$something = ($mode = $this->input->get('mode') or $mode = "default");` we would get `true` in `$something`. To make it clearer what I wrote above is evaluated like this:

```
($mode = $this->input->get('mode')) or ($mode = "default");
```

Comment: this only returns boolean result in any case

Comment: Did you bother to test? I did. It works fine. Notice that I used `or` and not `||`. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: As a matter of fact the whole expression is evaluated to a Boolean, but we don't care about that. We only care about the value of `$mode`.

Comment: sorry for last comment.. its really working.. and best for me

Comment: No problem and don't forget to make some time to read the Manual ;)

Comment: thanks for suggesting manual.. its all because assignmet(=) has higher precedence than (or). i tested this earlier by doing var_dump($a or $b) and did not make assignment

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could win anything by this premature optimization except a line of source:

```
if(!($mode = $this->input->get('mode'))) {
    $mode = 'default';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more readable way.

```
if(!($mode = $this->input->get('mode')))
$mode = 'default';
```

And a less readable way.

```
$mode = ($mode = $this->input->get('mode'))?$mode:'default';
```

Comment: this is the one i thought but is there any difference in performance

Comment: I think this is actually slower than the `if` because in either cases an assignment is performed.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If any falsy value (e.g. `null`, empty string, `0`) should be set to `'default'`, then this will do the job:</strike>

```
$mode = ($this->input->get('mode') || 'default');
```

This returns only boolean values, sorry.

Comment: this only returns boolean result in any case

Comment: You are right, I have not coded any PHP lately, so I was guessing it behaves like Javascript in this respect. Sorry.

Comment: This one really does return Boolean. Mine doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

[Ternary operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

```
$mode = ($this->input->get('mode')) ? $this->input->get('mode') : 'default';
```

EDIT:

If $this->input->get() operates at anything greater than O(n) don't use this.

Comment: isn't it calling a method twice to speed down

Comment: If $this->input->get('mode') operates at higher than O(n), it may slow down but if the function is a simple O(n), it becomes O(n+1), which is still just O(n).

Comment: `O(n+1)` may be equivalent to `O(n)`, but in terms of absolute speed, `O(n)` is faster than `O(n+1)`. `O(3000n)` is equivalent to `O(n)` too. Big-O notation shows you what the relative speed will be as `n` changes, not how long something will take.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mode = !empty($_GET['mode']) ? $this->input->get('mode') : 'default';
```

As your probably doing some sanitization within your `get` method then instead of using that to check if a variable is set, you can use `!empty` on the `$_GET`, as your only checking if isset theres no security issue what so ever, so this will check if the string is actually set, aswell as check if its empty.

if this result's to true, it will then fetch the sanitized version from your `get` method and assign it to `$mode`, otherwise will assign `default` to `$mode`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly in one line, but nevertheless.

```
if ( false === $mode = $this->input->get('mode') )
{
    $mode = 'default';    
}
```